# Kubernetes api not shows error pod status

Tags: c#, kubernetes

i tried ListPodForAllNamespaces() using Kubernetes API C# library .Using  Status.Phase property to get the current status of the pod.
when i tried to kubectl comman to get the pod status ,it is shows as  crashloop and error state.

```
kubectl get pods -n api
NAME                                 READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
test-web-api-78777-2zlwl             1/1     Running            0          9m8s
jobapp1-878787-knt46                 0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   5          4m53s
jobapp2-878787-knt46                 0/1     Error              5          4m53s
```

but if the pod status is error state ,the Kubernetes api shows as running.
below is my code

```
var config = KubernetesClientConfiguration.InClusterConfig();//for local testing BuildDefaultConfig && for cluster testing InClusterConfig
    var client = new Kubernetes(config);
    var namespaces = client.ListPodForAllNamespaces();
    foreach (var ns in namespaces.Items){
        Console.WriteLine(ns.Metadata.Name +" status - "+ns.Status.Phase);
    }
```

**OUTPUT IS**

> test-web-api-78777-2zlwl  status - Running
> jobapp1-878787-knt46 status - Running
> jobapp2-878787-knt46 status - Running

Comment: Based on name i guess two of pods are jobs. Could you share job/cronjob YAMLS you have used for those `jobapp`? Also provide output of `kubectl describe <pod_name> -n api`. In some scenarios pod could go `runnung > CrashLoopBackOff` but in most of the cases its just go straight to `CrashLoopBackOff` if there is something wrong. It would be good to reproduce this behavior and check if this scenario was `running > Crash`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither your `kubectl` command nor your `C#` kubernetes api is wrong.

You can see that the last two pods restarted 5 times. Each of them was in `Running` state for some time during restarting for 5 times.

When you ran your `C#` api, all of the pods were actually in `Running` phase.

If you run your `C#` api after waiting for a bit, you will see that they are not in `Running` phase.

Comment: ya.you are right.but still it shows as  pending state.is that correct ?

Comment: You should run `kubectl describe pod <pod-name> -n <namespace>` to see why the pods are being failed.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```sh
kubectl describe [-n namespace] pod [pod_id]
```

You may see something there that tells you why the pod is in a crashed state.. also you can check in the google cloud console whether anything is reported there.

Answer (score 0):

This Main Status may still show running if during the point of querying status was running, and later it can become something else, thus to escape this problem , I would suggest to use properties of pod object(type :V1PodList) from in K8client in C#  like  :

```
pod.Status.Conditions.Any(x=>x.Status== "False")
```

This will actualy give status of 4 conditions i.e `Initialized ,Ready,ContainersReady & PodScheduled`. For a successfull running pod , all 4 will be true , else atleast one of them will be false.